# How to update fetched json data to tableView by section asynchronously

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous

I fetched json data asynchronously from 3 urls. I appended the result of jsonDecoder to Array and their orders get changed everytime I launched my app, I know beacuse it's asynchronous.
So I saved urls to array `urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]`, I really really want to update each `url`'s index of array `urls` to tableView's section which index is same as the `url`'s index

NetworkModule class

```swift
jsonFilenames.forEach { (name) in
            let baseUrl = "https://~~~/"
            guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + name) else { return }

            session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else { return }

                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                do {
                    let baseAPIResponse = try jsonDecoder.decode(BaseAPIResponse<StoreItem>.self, from: data)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getData"), object: nil, userInfo: ["json": baseAPIResponse.body, "section": name])

                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Error in decoding json", jsonErr)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

Notification

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getData"), object: nil)

        tableview.dataSource = tableViewModel
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.separatorStyle = .none
    }

    private var headerSections = [String]()

    @objc fileprivate func onDidReceiveData(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfoDict = notification.userInfo else { return }
        let storeItems = userInfoDict["json"] as! [StoreItem]
        tableViewModel.storeItemsArray.append(storeItems)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tip : if this fetch inside the same vc you shouldn't use notificationCenter but reload the table directly inside the callback

for this you need to get index of `name` which will return the proper position of where you need to insert the returned array inside the nested array of sections and send it in `object` parameter in notificationcenter

```
let baseAPIResponse = try jsonDecoder.decode(BaseAPIResponse<StoreItem>.self, from: data)
let index = jsonFilenames.index(of:name)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getData"), object: "\(index)", userInfo: ["json": baseAPIResponse.body, "section": name])
```

Comment: Thanks, so now I know the index but the reason why appended the array of sections  like this `tableViewModel.storeItemsArray.append(storeItems)`, I don't know any other ways to reload tableView. tableViewModel is UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Do `tableViewModel.storeItemsArray.inser(storeItems,at:index)` but note `storeItemsArray` must have created with equal size of nested arrays as the urls

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dispatch Group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) to manage your async tasks. And wait until all the tasks are finished and then compose all the results collected by tasks. Then, send notification.

You can try something like the following. Note: It's not tested. Just want to demonstrate the idea on how to use dispatch group to manage your async tasks and aggregate the results in correct order you want.

```swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

  let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
  let results: [String] = Array(repeating: "", count: jsonFilenames.count)

  for (index, name) in jsonFilenames.enumerated() {
      let baseUrl = "https://~~~/"
      guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + name) else { return }
      downloadGroup.enter()
      session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
          guard let data = data else { return }

          let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
          jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

          do {
              let baseAPIResponse = try jsonDecoder.decode(BaseAPIResponse<StoreItem>.self, from: data)
              results[index](baseAPIResponse.body)
              downloadGroup.leave()
          } catch let jsonErr {
              print("Error in decoding json", jsonErr)
          }
      }.resume()
  }
  // it will wait all tasks to finish before continue, and block the current queue.
  // so it's better to excute the code in another queue other than main. That's the reason
  // why the code is executed inside DispatchQueue.global
  downloadGroup.wait()

  // If all your tasks finish successfully, results will has the right order. 
  // results[0] is the result of you first task. results[1] will be the second. Etc... 
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getData"), object: nil, userInfo: ["json": results, "section": name])
}
```

Comment: first no need for `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async` second `DispatchGroup` isn't needed as it'll not help partial update

Comment: @Sh_Khan according to my own understanding, He wants to show the results align with the order of  the async results of jsonFilenames. So, I guess DispatchGroup will be a good option. if DispatchGroup is used, why you think `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async` is not needed? I'd like to know that. Thank you.

Comment: `session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in` runs in background thread so no need for global queue

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes, correct, that's each async task. We are talking about when you're using `DispatchGroup`, when you call `wait`, it Waits synchronously for the previously submitted work to finish. So, it block the current queue. If you are using `DispatchGroup` in main queue, it will block the main queue.

Comment: why you block if you can run them asynchronous and insert in correct index